# count matching open ports in a network log file

Tags: text-processing, awk, nmap

I have network log file like this one:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.51
Host is up.
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
80/tcp   open     http
443/tcp  open     https
8080/tcp open     http-proxy
443/tcp  open     https
8080/tcp open     http-proxy
8082/tcp filtered redcap
8083/tcp filtered https-alt

Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.201
Host is up.
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
80/tcp   open   http
443/tcp  filtered https
8281/tcp filtered http-proxy
8080/tcp open     sedan
8801/tcp filtered https-alt

Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.17
Host is up.
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
80/tcp   closed   http
443/tcp  closed https
9081/tcp open      ecan

Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.10
Host is up.
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
80/tcp   closed   ftp
443/tcp  open   https
9081/tcp open      standard
```

I want to extract the IP addresses and the counts of open ports for every IP address so the result:

```
192.168.1.10 - 2
192.168.1.201 - 2
192.168.1.51 - 5
192.168.1.17 - 1
```

Comment: Just in case you weren't aware, there's (still) an `-oG` "greppable output" option for nmap.

Comment: @Jeff Schaller what you mean ? please explain?

Comment: I've added an answer with details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; FS="\n"} 
    {split($1,a," "); host[a[5]] = 0; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (match($i,"open") != 0) 
        host[a[5]]++} END{for (each in host) print each " - " host[each]}' file

192.168.1.10 - 2
192.168.1.201 - 2
192.168.1.51 - 5
192.168.1.17 - 1
```

In this command the record separator `RS` was set to a blank line `“”` and the field separator to a newline`\n`. Next, `awk` splits the first line of each record and capture the fifth item in the split array which is relevant to the IP address. After then, `Awk` iterates through the remaining fields `NF` looking for the string “open” in each field. When `open` is present then it will count for the relevant IP address in the host array. Finally, `awk` prints the results.

Comment: Thank you ! would you please explain the command so we understand how it works?

Comment: @Sam please see my edits and let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to have an nmap log file, if you have control over the invocation of nmap, consider the (deprecated) `-oG` option to create greppable output. For example:

```
$ nmap -oG /tmp/output.txt localhost
$ awk '/^Host: / && /Ports: / { num=gsub("/open/", ""); print $2, "-", num }' < /tmp/output.txt
127.0.0.1 - 6
```

This uses awk to parse the greppable output from nmap; the awk script looks for the "Host:" lines that also contain the string "Ports: "; it then counts the number of "/open/" strings and reports that number for each host.

Answer (score 0):

I would use below `awk` instead:

```
awk 'function output() { print ip, count; count=0 }
     /Nmap/ && count { output() }
     /Nmap/ { ip=$NF }
     /open/ { count++ }
END{ output() }' infile
```